Approximation Functions ApproxFun.jl
What variations of finite difference method algorithms are utilized in the implementation of the ApproxFun.eigs function for computing eigenvalues? Additionally, could you provide links to supplementary materials on this topic?
I tried to find different methods used in the ApproxFun.eigs function for computing eigenvalues. I expected to find various finite difference method algorithms.
